# gcc/clang C++: move constructors not called but required in a code like A a, b; A c(a+b);

Tags: c++, constructor, default, move

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
  char a;
public:
  A(): a('#') { cerr << "DEFAULT!" << endl; };
  A(char a): a(a) { cerr << "VALUE! " << a << endl;  };
  A(A const &o): a(o.a) { cerr << "COPY! " << o.a << endl; }
  // A(A && o): a(std::move(o.a)) { cerr << "MOVE!: " << o.a << endl; }
  // A(const A && o): a(std::move(o.a)) { cerr << "MOVE!(const): " << o.a << endl; }
  // A(volatile A && o): a(std::move(o.a)) { cerr << "MOVE!(volatile): " << o.a << endl; }
  // A(const volatile A && o): a(std::move(o.a)) { cerr << "MOVE!(const volatile): " << o.a << endl; }
  // A(A && o) = delete; // (***)
  friend A operator+(const A &o1, const A &o2){ A r; r.a = o1.a -'a' + o2.a; cerr << "+:" << r << endl; return r; }
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A& o) { out << o.a; return out; }
};

int main(){
  A a('a');
  A b('b');
  A c('c');
  cout << a << b << c << endl;
  A d(b+c); // <----- !!! WHO HANDLES THIS??? !!!
  A e(a);
  cout << a << b << c << d << e << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the line with 'WHO HANDLES THIS???' the magic happens, as the value is correctly transferred.

I assumed the default move constructor was called, so I overloaded it (and then all of them - see 4 commented lines), but to my surprise, no one get the call (if uncommented). Then I tried to delete the default copy constructor (anyway, according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor it should not be created by default, as I have copy constructor). This makes g++/clang++ to return error in WHO HANDLES THIS??? line, with message that default move constructor is deleted. clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1, g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0.

What the hell is happening here? Can anyone explain or point out to any specs?

Comment: Constant references can  be bound to bound to rvalues, no rvalue-reference constructor is needed for that.

Comment: Also note that for trivial cases the compiler will *elide* copying, but a vali copy-constructor is still needed.

Comment: *WHO HANDLES THIS???* The `operator+` handles this, as the `d` in constructed *in situ* (the other constructors are elided and the `r` is the `d`, in place).

Comment: Thanks! This ellision seems like a good and straightforward optimization idea, but I have never heard of it before... something new learned.

Comment: @RobertSzczelina that's only possible if your sources were more than 12 year old or more (it's elision with one `l`) so they couldn't know of guaranteed copy elision. NRVO here though is an optional feature which is allowed rather than guaranteed. Means you cannot count your beans by using sideeffects in constructor unless certain guidelines are followed

Comment: Aside, interesting is that, providing copy constructor and deleting move constructor prevents compilation. Explicitly deleting copy constructor and providing a move constructor still compiles and works (still with NMVO).

Anyway, the feature does not break the use cases for copy and move constructors that I can imagine in a non-academic, day-to-day code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HANDLER is easier to see if you add object addresses to your trace output.

This is due to one of the optimizations allowed for in the C++ standard.  Someday, it may even be required by the C++ standard.  (Updated, thanks Artyer.)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;

class A { 
    char ch{ '#' };
public:
    A() { cerr << "DEFAULT!\n"; }
    A(char ch_) : ch{ch_} { cerr << "VALUE! " << ch << "\n";  }
    A(A const& from) : ch{from.ch} { cerr << "COPY! " << ch << "\n"; }

    friend auto operator+(A const& a, A const& b) -> A { A r; r.ch = a.ch -'a' + b.ch; cerr << "+:" << r << " @ " << &r << "\n"; return r; }
    friend auto operator<<(ostream& out, const A& a) -> ostream& { return out << a.ch; }
};

int main() {
    A a{'a'};
    A b{'b'};
    A c{'c'};
    cout << a << b << c << "\n";
    cout << "About to make a d...\n";
    A d{b+c}; // <----- !!! WHO HANDLES THIS??? !!!
    cout << "...d@" << &d << " has been made!\n";
    A e{a};
    cout << a << b << c << d << e << "\n";
}
```

Comment: NRVO is still not required in C++23

Comment: Thanks!

Heck... C++ with each version get uglier and uglier...

Comment: @RobertSzczelina • There are some experiments underway for a less ugly future.  Like Herb Sutter's **C++ syntax 2** experiment, and Sean Baxter's **Circle** experiment and **New Circle** experiment.  There is hope.  But I don't think we'll see those experiments bear fruit for C++26.